# How to put Listview items into String Array?

Tags: android, listview

Im developing an app and as the title says how to put items of listview into String array, not string array to listview but listview to string array.

I've been searching for this but what I only found is putting String array items into listview.

Please help me thank you in advance.

To clarify this thread, the question is how to put listview items into String array.

Thanks. :D

Codes

```
public class DailyPlanTab extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

ListView dailyPlanList;

ArrayList<DailyManager> taskList = new ArrayList<DailyManager>();
DatabaseDailyPlan db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dailyplan_layout);

    dailyPlanList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvDailyPlanList);
    dailyPlanList.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    ImageView add = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivDailyPlanAdd);

    add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent newDailyIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    NewDailyPlan.class);
            startActivity(newDailyIntent);

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    taskList.clear();

    db = new DatabaseDailyPlan(getApplicationContext());
    db.getWritableDatabase();

    ArrayList<DailyManager> tempList = db.getTask();

    for (int i = 0; i < tempList.size(); i++) {

        String getTask = tempList.get(i).getDaily_name();
        String getDate = tempList.get(i).getDaily_date();
        int getId = tempList.get(i).getDaily_id();

        DailyManager dm = new DailyManager();
        dm.setDaily_name(getTask);
        dm.setDaily_date(getDate);
        dm.setDaily_id(getId);

        taskList.add(dm);
    }

    dailyPlanList.setAdapter(new ListAdapter(this));
    // db.close();

}

public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    public ListAdapter(Context c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return taskList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_checklist_item,
                    null);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.taskTitle = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvCheckListItem);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.taskTitle.setText(""
                + taskList.get(position).getDaily_name());

        return convertView;
    }
}

public class ViewHolder {

    TextView taskTitle, taskDate;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
        long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int taskId = taskList.get(position).getDaily_id();
    String taskName = taskList.get(position).getDaily_name();
    String taskDate = taskList.get(position).getDaily_date();

    Intent newPlan = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DailyPlan.class);
    newPlan.putExtra("task_id", taskId);
    newPlan.putExtra("task_name", taskName);

     startActivity(newPlan);
}
```

next is the information of the item inside the listview

```
 public class DailyPlan extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

final ArrayList<DailyManager> savedItems = new ArrayList<DailyManager>();

ListView checkList;

Boolean nextItem = false;
TempManager tm;
DatabaseTemp dbTemp;
Intent i;
int taskId = -1;
String taskName = " ", taskDate = null;

DatabaseDailyPlan db;
DailyManager dm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.saved_dailyplan);

    checkList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvCheckList);
    // checkList.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    try {
        i = getIntent();
        taskId = i.getExtras().getInt("task_id");
        taskName = i.getExtras().getString("task_name");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "From new id is" + taskId,
                5000).show();

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    Button addList = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAddList);

    addList.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // openDialog("", false, -1);
        }
    });

    if (nextItem) {
        // openDialog("", false, -1);
    }

}

public void refresh() {

    DailyPlan.this.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    savedItems.clear();

    dbTemp = new DatabaseTemp(getApplicationContext());
    dbTemp.getWritableDatabase();

    db = new DatabaseDailyPlan(getApplicationContext());
    db.getWritableDatabase();

    if (taskId != -1) { // / For Load

        ArrayList<DailyManager> savedList = db.getList(taskId);
        for (int i = 0; i < savedList.size(); i++) {

            String savedListItems = savedList.get(i).getDaily_list();
            String savedListTitle = savedList.get(i).getDaily_name();
            String savedListDate = savedList.get(i).getDaily_date();
            int savedListId = savedList.get(i).getDaily_id();

            DailyManager dm = new DailyManager();
            dm.setDaily_list(savedListItems);
            dm.setDaily_name(savedListTitle);
            dm.setDaily_date(savedListDate);
            dm.setDaily_id(savedListId);

            savedItems.add(dm);
        }
    } else { // / For New

    }
    checkList.setAdapter(new ListAdapter(this));
}

public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    public ListAdapter(Context c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return savedItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_checklist_item,
                    null);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.checkListItem = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvCheckListItem);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.checkListItem.setText(savedItems.get(position)
                .getDaily_list() + position);

        final int temp = position;

        return convertView;
    }
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView checkListItem;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int item, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // openDialog(savedItems.get(item).getDaily_name(), true,
    // savedItems.get(item).getDaily_id());
}
```

}

Comment: why do you need to put the items of listview in string array and how do you populate listview?

Comment: I populate listview using ListAdapter

Comment: post your code and why do you need a string array?

Comment: Because when I click the first listview, it will transfer to next activity that also has listview , which contains the information of the first listview

Comment: What i actually need is to save listview to database. And i guess string array is the way if you have a better way please help me.

Comment: post your code with which how can i help

Comment: I added the codes. the first code is the list of the Task, and when you click that it will go to another activity that gives its information

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you want to create your String Array like so and place this at the top of the Activity declaration:

```
private String[] stringArray = new String[listView.getCount()];
```

Then you'll want to find out how many items are in the list by using listView.getCount() and then you'll want to iterate through the list and add all of the values into the array you've made earlier. This can be done like so:

```
for(int i=0; i < listView.getCount(); i++)
{
    View v = list.getChildAt(i);
    TextView tv= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item);
    stringArray[i] = tv.getText();
}
```

Hope this helps and works! Let me know if not.

Comment: You can't create an array without a size.  Change first line to use "new String[listView.getCount()]".

Comment: That's true. I forgot about that. You can either set it to 0 inside the square brackets or you can do what @RickFalck has suggested.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to create array by the length of your columns
and create a for loop to assign every value in the array as below

```
string[] selected_item = new string[listView.SelectedItems.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < selected_item.Length; i++)
    {
        selected_item[i] = listView.SelectedItems[i].Text; 
    }
```